# Android app stopping unexpectedly when built...XML layout file problem?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I've built the bare bones of my app so far in Eclipse using an adapted version of the LunarLander app provided by Android Developers. I've adjusted bits and pieces and have no errors at all though when I run it in the emulator it keeps saying "the application has stopped unexpectedly" and i have to Force Close.

Is it possible that my main.xml layout file is causing this issue? Mine looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/distractions_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

but their's looks like:

```
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
```

-->

```
<com.example.android.lunarlander.LunarView
  android:id="@+id/lunar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
              android:text="@string/lunar_layout_text_text"
              android:visibility="visible"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:textColor="#88ffffff"
      android:textSize="24sp"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Could this be responsible for the app being unable to launch? If I need to post my code I will but its over 900 lines so thought I would just see if this was possibly the problem first?

Thanks to all that can enlighten me!

Comment: In Eclipse, you can open a view called LogCat *(Window > Show View > Other > Android > LodGat)*, that will display a log of everything that's happeding ; includind stack traces in case of a force close. Those are often quite helpful when it comes to finding the cause of a problem ;-)

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful, it would seem from looking at this that the problem does reside in this layout.

I'm getting an Android Runtime error with the message: 
"java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.darius.android.distractions
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout"

which causes the main thread to exit and several lines in the log stem from this exception. 

Have you any suggestions on how I might solve this?

Comment: Hard to say with the informations given here ; still, the stacktrace should give you more informations, like the line where there exception is thrown ? I'm guessing there is some cast that's not right...

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
```

This kind of error usually happens when you try and get the view object from your activity class and you cast it incorrectly.

Without seeing your activity classes code I can only guess but you may have something like this:

```
FrameLayout myLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.distractions_layout);
```

As *distractions_layout* is a **LinearLayout** and not a **FrameLayout** you will get that error. The correct way to do it would be like this:

```
Linearlayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.distractions_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your manifest file at all ? Sometimes having the wrong class name as the start-up activity can cause the application to not start at all.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Make sure in your manifest file that the XML above is correct for your own source, this may be the problem.